# Page title with colon, hyphen or parentheses and the capital letters

Tags: title, seo, page

I'm creating a website for a language school. It has a small navigation menu:

- Adults: elementary
- Adults: other
- Teenagers
- Kids

What is the right practice:

- Adults: elementary
- Adults - elementary
- Adults (elementary)

etc.

And should it be capitalized: *Elementary*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should probably use [English Capitalization Rules](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/capitalization-rules/).

As what you mention are titles, these rules should apply:

> **6. Capitalize Most Words in Titles**
>
> The capitalization rules for titles of books, movies, and other works
>   vary a little between style guides. In general, you should capitalize
>   the first word, all nouns, all verbs (even short ones, like is), all
>   adjectives, and all proper nouns. That means you should lowercase
>   articles, conjunctions, and prepositions—however, some style guides
>   say to capitalize conjunctions and prepositions that are longer than
>   five letters.

The same goes for punctuation: you should probably use a colon as a construct in your example "Adults: elementary" is a ["Title: subtitle" relationship](https://writingcenter.unc.edu/tips-and-tools/semi-colons-colons-and-dashes/):

> 3. To express time, in titles, and as part of other writing conventions. [...]
>
>    - With subtitles. Colons are used to separate titles from subtitles. *Example: Everest: The Last Frontier*

Answer (score 0):

When Elementary is the level name I think it should be in uppercase:

[image: English language levels description]

[Source](https://tracktest.eu/english-levels-cefr/)

Comment: As you see on my menu "elementary" is an adjective, not a noun: elementary level vs. other levels. See also: [English level](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/content) and [CEFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages).